# Как сделать чтобы была проверка на количество символов?

Tags: c#

В тексте G элементы разбить на слоги и записать со знаками тире в новый массив (слогом считать элемент слова, имеющий количество букв > 1 и заканчивающийся гласным, например: абракадабра => абра-ка-да-бра).

```
char[] glas1 = { 'и', 'о', 'у', 'е', 'а', 'ї' };

string str = "абракадабра";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    builder.Append(str[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < glas1.Length; j++)
    {
        if (str[i] == glas1[j])
        {
            builder.Append('-');
        }
    }
}

string word = builder.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(word);
```

Код выводит: а-бра-ка-да-бра-

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так решается.

```
char[] glas1 = { 'и', 'о', 'у', 'е', 'а', 'ї' };

string str = "абракадабра";
StringBuilder sb = new();
int count = 0;
foreach (char c in str)
{
    sb.Append(c);
    count++;
    if (count > 1 && glas1.Contains(c))
    {
        sb.Append('-');
        count = 0;
    }
}
if (sb[^1] == '-')
    sb.Length--;

Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

```
абра-ка-да-бра
```

Кстати, есть еще гласные `ё`, `э`, `ы`.